# Qt application crashes on MacOs at launching

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I launch my application and it immediately crashed, in general, I don't why, but I know that I moved it from 4.8 qt version to 5.12 qt version. I got the error message as below:

```
    User ID:               502
    Date/Time:             2019-04-15 12:05:42.546 +0300
    OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
    Report Version:        12

    Time Awake Since Boot: 260000 seconds
    System Integrity Protection: enabled
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
    Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
    Terminating Process:   exc handler [45798]

    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010fc65a6f QObject::moveToThread(QThread*) + 31
```

Code:

```
   ControlSetting::ControlSetting(Controller* controller, QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
   {
        impl = PtrControllSettingsPrivate(new ControllerSettingsPrivate(controller, this));

        QThread* thread = new QThread();
        thread->setObjectName("ControllerSetting");
        this->moveToThread(thread);
        connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(Start()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        thread->start();
    }
```

And additional information from the crash report:

```
    Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
      rax: 0xe8758948f07d8948  rbx: 0x000000010a6bb340  rcx: 0x00007fa0da522701  rdx: 0x000000010a486cd3
      rdi: 0x00007fa0da570650  rsi: 0x00007fa0da563450  rbp: 0x00007ffee5784cd0  rsp: 0x00007ffee5784c70
      r8: 0x000000000da5084b   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007ffee5785b28  r11: 0x000000011660fa50
      r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x00007fa0da570650  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00007fa0da563450
      rip: 0x000000011660fa6f  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000010a4c98f0

      Logical CPU:     0
      Error Code:      0x00000000
      Trap Number:     13
```

My stack:

```
   Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
   0   org.qt-project.QtCore            0x000000010fc65a6f QObject::moveToThread(QThread*) + 31
   1   com.w.Desktop                    0x000000010c28bfcb ControlSetting:: ControlSetting(Controller*, QObject*) + 459 (ControlSetting:347)
   2   com.w.Desktop                    0x000000010c28c275 ControlSetting::ControlSetting(Controller*, QObject*) + 37 (ControlSetting:351)
   3   com.w.Desktop                    0x000000010c0682cc Controller::Controller(QObject*) + 908 (Controller:645)
   4   com.w.Desktop                    0x000000010c06a05d Controller::Controller(QObject*) + 29 (Controller:798)
   5   com.w.Desktop                    0x000000010c05edff Application::Setup() + 2943 (Application.cpp:276)
   6   com.w.Desktop                    0x000000010c03df4a main + 490 (main.cpp:161)
   7   libdyld.dylib                    0x00007fff766fe3d5 start + 1
```

Comment: It is good that you intended to include a crash log. It is bad that it is only small part of it. Before you include full crash log please decode it first.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Run `Console.app` on the left find where your app drops logs and crash logs and find matching crash log. For decoding you need build symbols and use `atos` tool.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to debug this.  That will probably be too large (but trying to produce it would be worthwhile anyway).  I suggest starting the application under the debugger and looking at the call stack.

Comment: @MartinBonner this look like configuration issue so providing MCVE is hard almost impossible. If he is able to provide one then he is able to understand and fix the issue.

Comment: @Eorlindr most important part is call stack under `Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread`. If you will see it and if it contains reference to your code, please include your code too.

Comment: @MarekR Yes.  That is why I said "trying to produce it would be worthwhile anyway".  Also, I don't think this question is a good fit for the site.  The OP doesn't have a single, easily describable problem which can be answered here; they need a tutorial on how to debug the problem.

Comment: sorry for delay, I added  stack, also when I comented the "moveToThread" it contiue crash but now on "0x0000000111753f63 QObject::connect(QObject const*, char const*, QObject const*, char const*, Qt::ConnectionType) + 1027"